# Computer connects to lan, but not the internet

Tags: windows-vista, internet, troubleshooting, connection

I have a computer with Vista Home that can connect to the router, but it cannot get on the internet. I cannot ping google.com, the request times out. I've tried this on two separate networks and have no trouble with other computers connecting.

I've renewed ipconfig, reset winsock, updated the wireless adapter, and the hosts file looks fine. I've tried disabling the firewall as well as a direct wired connection. I did a scan with Norton and it didn't find anything. Is there anything else I can try before resorting to a system restore?

**Update** (Copied from Answer)

Windows Update was able to find updates and install them (though, they could have already been downloaded previously). When I pinged Google by using their IP 66.102.9.103, it said it lost 25 percent of the packets. I successfully flushed the DNS but it didn't help. Also, I found safe mode with networking works fine.

Answer (score 3):

How about calling your ISP? If you can't connect even directly connected it could be an issue with the modem and/or your actual connection.

**Edit**: Since other computers on the same LAN seem to be connecting as well, its most likely an issue with that one computer.

Some follow up would be to check and make sure you have the *correct* driver.

Also I'd try to see if I still have the same problems booting into `safe mode with networking`.

Comment: I'd agree with that.

Comment: Other computers have no trouble getting on the same network. Also, I'm having this issue on other networks.

Comment: And you're sure you have the correct driver?

Answer (score 2):

Check the IP settings of your connection. I'm assuming with the router in place you want it to act as your DHCP server, so make sure your IP information is not statically set.

Answer (score 1):

Check your router DNS setup, try these [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) DNS servers:

> 208.67.222.222 (primary)
>
> 208.67.220.220 (secondary)

And the same for you NIC config.

try to ping to an IP adress ie: 66.102.9.103 (this is google one) to see if this is a DNS related problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Reset TCP/IP (Internet Protocol) in Windows Vista**

1. Click on Start button.
2. Type **Cmd** in the Start Search text box.
3. Press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** keyboard shortcut to run Command Prompt as Administrator. Allow elevation request.
4. Type **netsh int ip reset** in the Command Prompt shell, and then press the Enter key.
5. Restart the computer.

*if you're using a static IP address, you will have to enter the settings again, as this will reset the TCP/IP to Windows default (automatically).*

**Flush DNS Resolver Cache in Windows Vista**

1. Click on Start button.
2. Type **Cmd** in the Start Search text box.
3. Press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** keyboard shortcut to run Command Prompt as Administrator. Allow elevation request.
4. In the command window type the following and then hit enter: **ipconfig /flushdns**

You will see the following confirmation:

> Windows IP Configuration Successfully
>   flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.